# Jquery: Dynamic adding <id> depending on <div>

Tags: jquery, html

Let's dynamically add IDs on our DIV tag, depending on the number of DIVs

```
<div class="panel" id="">
  ...
  ...
</div>
<div class="panel" id="">
  ...
  ...
</div>
<div class="panel" id="">
  ...
  ...
</div>
```

the result that we would like to achieve is using jquery

```
<div class="panel" id="1">
  ...
  ...
</div>
<div class="panel" id="2">
  ...
  ...
</div>
<div class="panel" id="3">
  ...
  ...
</div>
```

i tried to do a code like this but it is not working

```
$panel.each(function(i) {
  $(this).attr('id', ($(i+1)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.panel').each(function(i) {
  $(this).attr('id', i+1);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rjptR/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the last line:

```
  $(this).attr('id', ($(i+1)));
```

Why do you wrap `i+1` with `($())`?

It should be just

```
  $(this).attr('id', i+1);
```

Comment: thanks andrey! i don't know the basic coding yet. i know what to use just that i don't know how to use them. but i know i'll remember them next time. thanks again andrey!

Answer (score 0):

```
i=0;
$('.panel').each(function() {
    i++;
    $(this).attr('id', i);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(
        function () {
            var counter = 1;
            $(".panel").each(
                function () {
                    $(this).attr("id", counter);
                    counter++;
                }
            );
        }
);
```